# How can I increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph setting in my WP7 app

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 app which is pulling data via a WCF service. I'm sending quite a lot of data and blew the default MaxItemInObjectGraph setting.

I changed this on the server but now need to do the same on the client. I can't do it via the client config file as the behaviors element is not supported under WP7 so I will have to do it in code.

I have looked around and found the following code (which will hopefully do the job) but have no ideas where to implement it.

```
foreach ( var operation in channelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.Operations )  
{  
    var behavior = operation.Behaviors.Find() as DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior;  
    if ( behavior != null )  
    {  
        behavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;      
    }  
}
```

Where should I put this code?

Comment: I answered in your other one :)  .MaxItemsInObjectGraph defaults to Int.MaxValue in Silverlight. So you are saying you are exceeding the Int32.Max with your data?

Comment: Raised a new question as the first one seemed to be going off topic. But yes, you don't need to do this as the default works. Might be worth adding this as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to set MaxItemsInObjectGraph on WP7 client side as Silverlight defaults it to Int32.MaxValue.